# Pass the query result to the function

Tags: postgresql, function, triggers

I created a function that takes as a parameter a string by which i am looking for the desired element in the `Bus` table. After that i create a trigger that will fire after inserting into the `Maintenance` table. Here i have a problem: i specify that when changing the table, call the function and pass the last added element there, but the trigger is not created.

I looked for similar questions and saw that you need to take the query in brackets, but it did not help.

Ask for your help!

Function:

```
create function set_status(model_ varchar(50)) returns void as $$
    update Bus set technical_condition = 'don`t work' where model = model_;
    $$ LANGUAGE sql;
```

Trigger:

```
create trigger check_insert
    after insert on Maintenance
    for each row
    execute procedure set_status((select model from Maintenance order by id_m desc limit 1));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off your trigger function must be of the form:

```
create or replace function <function_name>() 
   returns trigger  
  language plpgsql
as $$
begin 
    ... 
end;
$$;
```

The language specification may come either before the code or after it. Moreover it must be defined **returning trigger** and as taking no parameters. See [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/plpgsql-trigger.html#PLPGSQL-DML-TRIGGER).  

You can achieve what you want by moving the `select status ...` query into the trigger function itself.

```
create or replace function set_status() 
  returns trigger
 language plpgsql
as $$
begin 
    update bus 
       set technical_condition =  
           (select model 
              from maintenance 
              order by id_m desc 
              limit 1
           ) ;
     return null;
end; 
$$; 

create trigger check_insert
    after insert on maintenance
    for each row
    execute procedure set_status();
```

**NOTE:** Not Tested.

Comment: yeah, it`s work! (you forgot about ```end```)

Comment: I did. Thanks for letting me know. Updated.